# Increment a variable based on number of items in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am relatively new to PS, but using PS within a wider IaC workflow. I have the following script, which checks for number of services installed, and increments the port number variable by 1.

```
$Service = Get-Service Test* | Select-Object Name
If( $Service.Name.count -eq 0){
$port = 12000 }
If( $Service.Name.count -eq 1){
$port = 12001 }
If ( $Service.Name.Count -eq 2){
$port = 12002 }
If ( $Service.Name.Count -eq 3){
$port = 12003 }
```

Unfortunately, this is not as dynamic as I would like, as the script will fail if there is more than 3 services.
How can I dynamically increment the port number based on number of services that exist? The port number starts at 12000, then if another service is installed, the port will be 12001, and if a third service is detected, the port number is 12002 and so on.

Comment: `$port = 12000 + $service.count`.

Comment: Thank you! worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the advice in [comment by AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62558427/increment-a-variable-based-on-number-of-items-in-powershell#comment110632078_62558427) if you *ensure* that the `$Service` object is a collection:

```
$Service = @(Get-Service Test* | Select-Object Name)
$port = 12000 + $Service.Count
```

Otherwise, you encounter the following errors:

```
$Service = Get-Service Test* ; $Service; $Service.Count
```

> ```
> The property 'Count' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
> At line:1 char:42
> + $Service = Get-Service Test* ; $Service; $Service.Count
> +                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
> ```

```
$Service = Get-Service Te* ; $Service; $Service.Count
```

> ```
> Status   Name               DisplayName                           
> ------   ----               -----------                           
> Running  TermService        Remote Desktop Services               
> The property 'Count' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
> At line:1 char:40
> + $Service = Get-Service Te* ; $Service; $Service.Count
> +                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
> ```

Comment: Thanks, the suggestion by AdminOfThings worked for me